# Работа с контролами в разных потоках

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

На форме есть stackpanel. Добавляю TextBlock, который создан во втором потоке в stackpanel, которая создана в первом.
[image: Вот код.]

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете связывать UI контролы, которые созданы в разных потоках. Каждое окно может содержать только контролы, созданные из одного потока - того же из которого создано окно.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы можете посоветовать как быть тогда?

Comment: @JDS_ создавайте контролы там же, где добавляете. Например `panel.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ panel.add(new TextBox(){Text = "...."}) })`

Comment: Спасибо, чет в голову не пришло.